# ggplot: label points with plotmath expressions

Tags: r, ggplot2, expression

I tried several methods to add superscript "+" with other strings as point labels in plot in R but it failed.

for example:

I know how to add single superscript "+" below:
plot(1:10,xlab = expression("ABC"^"+"))

It really work when I just want to add superscript "+" on x axis through xlab.

But I want to add multiple points with superscript labels, such as  expression("EFG"^"+"), expression("HIJ"^"+")  and so on.

When I put it into ggplot2, error information appeared:

```
Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type <expression>. Defaulting to continuous.
Error in `geom_text_repel()`:
! Problem while computing aesthetics.
i Error occurred in the 2nd layer.
Caused by error in `compute_aesthetics()`:
! Aesthetics are not valid data columns.
x The following aesthetics are invalid:
x `label = hh`
i Did you mistype the name of a data column or forget to add `after_stat()`?
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
>
```

Here is my reproducible example code:

```
library(ggrepel)
library(ggplot2)
data <- data.frame(x = 1:3,                 # Create example data
                   y = 1:3,
                   label = LETTERS[1:3])
data  

hh<-c(expression("ABC"^"+"),
      expression("EFG"^"+"),
      expression("HJK"^"+"))
plot(data$x,                                # Draw plot
     data$y,
     xlim = c(1, 4))
text(data$x,                                # Add labels
     data$y,
     labels = hh,
     pos = 4)

ggplot(data = data,aes(x=x,y=y))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_text_repel(aes(label = hh))
```

I hope somebody can give me some advice. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `hh` doesn't need to be expressions, it just needs to contain the text of the expression. We add `geom_text_repel(..., parse=TRUE)` so that it treats the `character` strings as expressions correctly.
2. I think the better way to define that expression is as `'ABC^"+"'` or `"ABC^'+'"` so that the `+` is not interpreted as the math operator.
3. *Technique*, I prefer to have the labels as part of the frame, so I'll add it to `data`, overriding your `label`. (But this is certainly not required, it's just "cleaner", in my opinion.)

```r
data <- data.frame(x = 1:3,                 # Create example data
                   y = 1:3,
                   label = c("ABC^'+'", "EFG^'+'", "HJK^'+'"))
set.seed(42) # since ggrepel is stochastic, not required in production
ggplot(data = data,aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text_repel(aes(label = label), parse = TRUE)
```

[image: ggplot with expressions in text labels]

(I added `set.seed(42)` purely so that you can get exactly this image, since the repel action is random. I recommend not using `set.seed` unless you find one specific seed which lays out the labels in a way you prefer. Without setting the seed, you will get a slightly-different plot each time you call it.)

Comment: That's what I want. I misunderstand the expression function and it wastes much of my time.  Thank you very much. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer r2evans' answer, but here's another way using `annotate`:

```
set.seed(1)
ggplot(data = data,aes(x=x,y=y))+
    geom_point()+
    annotate(geom = "text_repel", x = data$x, y = data$y, label = hh)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Your answer is great though there is a little bit flaw.